# MacOSX 10.8 , xcode 4.6.1 error Cocoa: "Color type user defined runtime attributes on OS X versions prior to 10.7"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.6

I got a warning in Xcode 4.6.1/Mac OSX 10.8 when I try to open an Xib file which used to work well in Xcode 3.x/ Mac OSX 10.7

"The file "MQMPlugIn.xib" has a dependency on an Interface Builder 3 plug-in.
Please choose "Upgrade" below to remove this dependency.
Some changes to the document may be destructive and cannot be undone."

If I click on the Upgrade button, I get several compile errors on xib file.

Cocoa: "Color type user defined runtime attributes on OS X versions prior to 10.7" .

[ If I select cancel the Interface builder won't open ].

I tried to change the user defined runtime attributes[ on bevel button, and other widgets] - color type, and even removed the user defined run time attribute [color type] in IDentity inspector, still no luck. Also tried changing the .xib version to 4.6 using the file inspector. Request help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 4.x stopped custom plugin support for xib. Our project had a custom plugin dependency. To solve this we have to click on the upgrade button, and then we have to replace all the custom controls [ which were part of the custom plugin ] with standard controls.